# Reading and writing to physical memory using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dma, memory-access

Is there any way to directly access the physical memory using Python? I am using Windows 7 x64 and Python 2.7. For example, I would like to read the double word present in the address **0xfb000000**. And then write to the same/another memory address. I have tried executing the following piece of code that crashes Python.

```
import ctypes
N=2
addr='0xfb000000'
g = (ctypes.c_int*N).from_address(int(addr,16))
print g[0]
```

The crash is probably due to permission issues. So, is there a way to gain permission to access the memory this way? Or, is there any other way to accomplish the read/write? I need to check some registers in the PCI express config space.

Comment: Does your code work when you start python as an Admin?

Comment: would it not be `ctypes.c_char*N` if it's a word? dono if it matters though, never tried this myself.

Comment: why addr '0xfb000000' is that address accessible from your process ?

Comment: No, still crashes even when I start as Admin.

Comment: I need to check some registers in the PCI express config space. 0xfb000000 is just an example.

Comment: Well, if it crashes, can you provide a back trace?
I'm assuming that your python process does not have adequate privileges to access that segment of the memory.

Comment: There is no backtrace. Python crashes immediately when I execute the aforementioned code, without any error message. It simply says python.exe has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should look at mmap module to map a virtual address for you to access in user space? you can't access ring0 directly in Vista and newer OS.